Patch not uninstalling due to found dependent in WiXv4
I have installed the patch bundle and when uninstalled the patch bundle I observed that the package is not removed, in the log, it says :
Will not uninstall package: [packagename], found dependents:
Found dependent: [GUID], name: [patchname]

It would be helpful if you could provide a solution for why this issue with dependents is occurring with WiXv4. This problem was not observed with WiXv3
